# Get 3D model's height and its transformed screen coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm rendering a Collada (*.dae) file with `ARKit`. As an overlay of my `ARSCNView` I'm adding a `SKScene` that simply shows a message bubble (without text yet).

Currently, I know how to modify the position of the bubble so that it looks like it's always at the feet of my 3D model. I'm doing like this:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval)  {
    if let overlay = sceneView.overlaySKScene as? BubbleMessageScene {            
        guard let borisNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "boris", recursively: true) else { return }

        let boxWorldCoordinates = sceneView.scene.rootNode.convertPosition(borisNode.position, from:sceneView.scene.rootNode.parent)
        let screenCoordinates = self.sceneView.projectPoint(boxWorldCoordinates)
        let boxY = overlay.size.height - CGFloat(screenCoordinates.y)

        overlay.bubbleNode?.position.x = CGFloat(screenCoordinates.x) - (overlay.bubbleNode?.size.width)!/2
        overlay.bubbleNode?.position.y = boxY
    }
}
```

However my bubble is always at the *feet* of the 3D model because I can only get the SCNNode position of my model, where it is anchored. I would like it to be at the head of my model.

Is there a way I can get the height of my 3D model, and then its transformed screen coordinates, so no matter where I am with my phone it looks like the bubble message is always next to the head?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each SCNNode has a `boundingBox` property which is the:

> The minimum and maximum corner points of the object’s bounding box.

So what this means is that:

> Scene Kit defines a bounding box in the local coordinate space using two points identifying its corners, which implicitly determine six axis-aligned planes marking its limits. For example, if a geometry’s bounding box has the minimum corner {-1, 0, 2} and the maximum corner {3, 4, 5}, all points in the geometry’s vertex data have an x-coordinate value between -1.0 and 3.0, inclusive.

If you look in SceneKit Editor you will also be able to see the size of your model in meters (I am saying this simply as a point you can refer to in order to check the calculations):

[image]

In my example I am using a Pokemon model with the size above.

I scaled the model (which you likely did as well) e.g:

```
 pokemonModel.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
```

So in order to get the `boundingBox` of the `SCNNode` we can do this:

```
/// Returns The Original Width & Height Of An SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter node: SCNNode
func getSizeOfModel(_ node: SCNNode){

     //1. Get The Size Of The Node Without Scale
     let (minVec, maxVec) = node.boundingBox
     let unScaledHeight = maxVec.y - minVec.y
     let unScaledWidth = maxVec.x - minVec.x

     print("""
         UnScaled Height = \(unScaledHeight)
         UnScaled Width = \(unScaledWidth)
           """)
    }
```

Calling it like so:

```
 getSizeOfModel(pokemonModel)
```

Now of course since our SCNNode has been scaled this doesn't help much so obviously we need to take this into account, by re-writing the function:

```
/// Returns The Original & Scaled With & Height On An SCNNode
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - node: SCNode
///   - scalar: Float
func getOriginalAndScaledSizeOfNode(_ node: SCNNode, scalar: Float){

     //1. Get The Size Of The Node Without Scale
     let (minVec, maxVec) = node.boundingBox
     let unScaledHeight = maxVec.y - minVec.y
     let unScaledWidth = maxVec.x - minVec.x

     print("""
         UnScaled Height = \(unScaledHeight)
         UnScaled Width = \(unScaledWidth)
         """)


     //2. Get The Size Of The Node With Scale
     let max = node.boundingBox.max
     let maxScale = SCNVector3(max.x * scalar, max.y * scalar, max.z * scalar)

     let min = node.boundingBox.min
     let minScale = SCNVector3(min.x * scalar, min.y * scalar, min.z * scalar)

     let heightOfNodeScaled = maxScale.y - minScale.y
     let widthOfNodeScaled = maxScale.x - minScale.x

     print("""
         Scaled Height = \(heightOfNodeScaled)
         Scaled Width = \(widthOfNodeScaled)
         """)

}
```

Which would be called like so:

```
 getOriginalAndScaledSizeOfNode(pokemonModel, scalar: 0.01)
```

Having done this you say you want to position a 'bubble' above your model, which could then be done like so:

```
func getSizeOfNodeAndPositionBubble(_ node: SCNNode, scalar: Float){

     //1. Get The Size Of The Node Without Scale
     let (minVec, maxVec) = node.boundingBox
     let unScaledHeight = maxVec.y - minVec.y
     let unScaledWidth = maxVec.x - minVec.x

     print("""
         UnScaled Height = \(unScaledHeight)
         UnScaled Width = \(unScaledWidth)
         """)

     //2. Get The Size Of The Node With Scale
     let max = node.boundingBox.max
     let maxScale = SCNVector3(max.x * scalar, max.y * scalar, max.z * scalar)

     let min = node.boundingBox.min
     let minScale = SCNVector3(min.x * scalar, min.y * scalar, min.z * scalar)

     let heightOfNodeScaled = maxScale.y - minScale.y
     let widthOfNodeScaled = maxScale.x - minScale.x

     print("""
         Scaled Height = \(heightOfNodeScaled)
         Scaled Width = \(widthOfNodeScaled)
         """)

     //3. Create A Buubble
     let pointNodeHolder = SCNNode()
     let pointGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.04)
     pointGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
     pointNodeHolder.geometry = pointGeometry

     //4. Place The Bubble At The Origin Of The Model, At The Models Origin + It's Height & At The Z Position

     pointNodeHolder.position = SCNVector3(node.position.x, node.position.y + heightOfNodeScaled, node.position.z)
          self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pointNodeHolder)

}
```

This yields the following result (which I also tested on a few other unfortunate Pokemon as well):

[image]

You will probably want to add a bit of 'padding' as well to the calculation, so that the node is a bit higher up than the top of the model e.g:

```
 pointNodeHolder.position = SCNVector3(node.position.x, node.position.y + heightOfNodeScaled + 0.1, node.position.z)
```

I am not great at Maths, and this uses an SCNNode for the bubble rather than an `SKScene`, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you, actually this sentence made me get it : _The minimum and maximum corner points of the object’s bounding box._ I didn't understood that it was **corners** of the box that I was getting with this function. And of course thank you for all the details that are gonna save me some time! Much obliged.

Comment: @BlackMirrorz I am getting wrong bounding box width and depth for unscaled model. Only height is right. Any specific reason for this behaviour. I am doing it in objective c. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can get borisNode.boundingBox : (float3, float3) to calculate the size of the node, you get a tuple of 2 points, then calculate the heigh by subtracting the y from one point from the other. Finally move your overlay's Y position by the number you get.